# Using armadillo in atom with script

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I there a way to compile a c++ file using script in atom that uses armadillo? I couldn't find anything related to it.

I already installed armadillo and tried compiling some basic code using script in atom:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  arma::arma_rng::set_seed_random();

  arma::Mat<double> A = arma::randu(4,4);
  std::cout << "A:\n" << A << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "thread-local wrapper routine for arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance", referenced from:
      arma::arma_rng::set_seed(unsigned long long) in test1-83e853.o
      arma::arma_rng::randu<double>::fill(double*, unsigned long long) in test1-83e853.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: How are you invoking your compiler?

Comment: Im using the package script in atom: https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script

Comment: Okay, how does _that_ invoke the compiler? Don't you have to setup include paths or libraries somewhere?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I should look for. The script package is completely automated, I don't need to setup anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the [source code for this atom-script thing](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/9d5f0e22e95efd4f98de1afb47138e5dc784ccdf/lib/grammars/c.coffee) correctly, it just hardcodes `-Wall -include stdio.h` as compilation options. You need to add `-larmadillo` to link it to the Armadillo library.

In short: you cannot use atom-script in combination with custom libraries, unless you edit the extension to hardcode the libraries in your compilation commandline.

Comment: I added -larmadillo in the config file and it worked afterwards. So thank you very much!